# Oracle 11g client access from classic asp

Tags: oracle, asp-classic, oracle11g, webserver, oracleclient

We have a web page in asp which accesses Oracle data using the oracle client. We're having trouble getting the asp to access the oracle client for Oracle 11g. With Oracle 10g we had to give the anonymous authentication user access to the OracleXE client folder. This would give the asp pages access to the oracle client. It's hard to tell what folders would need access to with oracle 11g client. We've given access to all of the oracle folders that we could find, but the asp pages still can't access the oracle 11g client.

Perhaps the asp page has to access something else for the oracle 11g client. Does anyone have any expience with this?

Comment: What is the exact errormessage encountered?

Answer (score 0):

Did you yet reboot after installing the Oracle client software? Perhaps IIS has not discovered that the software is in the PATH.